# Add watermark to PDF document

Tags: apex, visualforce, document

Is there any way to add watermark to certain PDF files stored in document folder?
 We would like to do a dynamic watermarking capability to the documents with confidential information of user who download the document. Is there a way to accomplish this or do we need to use a third party tool to make it happen?
In our case we have a VF page that displays the document assigned to them and they document the files from there.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can do this when you render a visualforce page as a pdf.

Just create a static resource that has your watermark image, and add the following lines to your Visualforce Page.

```
<style>

.watermark {
                background-repeat: repeat;
                background-image: url("{!URLFOR($Resource.WatermarkImage)}");
                }

</style>

<body class="watermark">

<!-- some more stuff in here  -->

</body>
```

This will work when you render a visualforce page as a pdf.

You may need to wrap your document PDF to be displayed in a page like the one described above. If that's the case, you should check out this solution to render PDF in visualforce :

[How to render PDF documents in visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7257/display-pdf-with-visualforce)

Comment: Hi Mitch, in the future, you can use the code button (`{}` or Ctrl-K) to format your code in a gray code block with syntax highlights and proper spacing. I've went ahead and updated this answer for you.